# With Immutable Records in React + Typescript, use private methods to generate properties upon Record instantiation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, record, immutable.js

I am trying to implement Immutable Records in a typescript project of mine at the suggestion of a colleague, but am running into an issue where I need to set some of the properties of the record using internal, private methods of the Record within the constructor.

Since all modifications to a record require a new object to be created, I can't seem to assign values to anything within the constructor of the Record without it yelling at me.

I've written up a contrived example, illustrating what I'm trying to do as if it was a standard class:

```
class Test {
    public myProp: number;
    constructor (param: number) {
        this.myProp = this._privateMethod(param);
    }
    private _privateMethod (arg: number) {
        return arg * 2;
    }
}
```

But since props on an immutable record can only be changed by creating a new object, I can't seem to find a way to get this to work.

```
class Test extends Record ({
    myProp: 0,
}) {
    public myProp: number;
    constructor (param: number) {
        // assign myProp to the result of _privateMethod(param)
    }
    private _privateMethod (arg: number) {
        return arg * 2;
    }
}
```

In this case, I can't use the same line within the constructor:

Code: `this.myProp = this._privateMethod(param);`

Error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot set on an immutable record.`

I even tried using the set() method of Records, even though I can't return the new Record with the updated prop anyway, but it still produced an error:

Code: `const updatedRecord = this.set('myProp', this._privateMethod(param));`

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined`

I can't believe that there would be no way to perform this action with a Record as it seems to be a pretty fundamental capability to me, so I'm going to chalk this up to unfamiliarity with Immutable.js. If anyone knows how I can achieve this, I would very much appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you change `public myProp` to `private myProp` and then create `public getProp() { return myProp; }`

Comment: I just tried that, but I am still getting the same errors when trying to assign `this.myProp` to anything within the constructor.

Comment: how about using `super(this._privateMethod(param));`